# geocoder - c is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, geocoding

So I was using the example of google itself by putting this on my website:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            if (geocoder)
            {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'australia' }, function (results, status)
                {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                    {
                        console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
                    } 

                    else
                    {
                        console.log('No results found: ' + status);
                    }
                });
             }
```

But I get an error "c is undefined"
Anyone can help ?

Script from google has been successfully added to my header.
I am already using a second script to display the map and this does work.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: I'm using essentially identical code. Can you provide the stack trace with the error?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error message "c is undefined" if you run the geocoder javascript on a Windows 2012 server through Firefox browser. However, it works fine in IE and Chrome. Also, if I run the same script on a Windows 2003 server using Firefox, it works OK and does not give me the error. Have you tried these browsers and what is the server that runs your code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firebug?  If so, close it and your script should work without errors.